# Need to encode/decode a JSON response for passing it to another webpage

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am having an website application, where I need to pass one JSON response(in string Format) across the site. I have used the hidden type value and passing it on submit of the link/button which triggers another page.
When Checked on WAF, It is throwing an cross-site scripting error. Since, the response contains special characters, I suspect this as the root cause of the issue.                    Now, I want to pass the JSON response in encoded format and decode it on the next webpage. I have read many articles and post on this. Can anyone suggest any best practice implementation on this.

Code snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="empStatus" id="empStatus" value=""> //in JSP

$("#empStatus").val(JSON.stringify(empStatus)); //in JS
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the encodeURIComponent before sending

$("#empStatus").val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(empStatus))); //in JS

and the decodeURIComponent when receiving,

thus it will protect from special enclosing characters like "